# Recommended way to create a bootable USB including the software used

Tags: windows, usb, windows-10, installation

I have an USB from which I want to install my OS (Windows 10). Once that's done, I install VS, Notepad++, Paint.NET, SQL Studio and a lot of other stuff that's nice to have.

All the stuff, I install manually after the OS installation's completed. Then, we also have all the settings and other stuff.

I wonder, is it easily possible to create such an USB installation drive as I have now **but with the addition** that all the stuff I want added and all the settings that I've done, are included?

The I'm-loving-it scenario would be if I can put my thing into a hole and after a short while get a computer that's freshly reinstalled with all the stupid stuff I might have done gone.

After that I only need to worry about backing up the genius stuff I surely have done...

Comment: Short version: Install Windows, install software, make image, use that image to install next time.

Comment: I might be slow on my brains, because I'm not getting a certain part of the process. It's the step #3 - *make image* - that I don't see. How does one "make image" of the system? I've done that when playing with virtual machines - that's easily understandable. But when I'm on my system and it's the physical computer - how exactly do I create an image **and** make it a bootable USB? Talk to me like if I'm five years old.

Comment: An "image" is not (usually) bootable. it's a full image backup.  Instructions on one of many ways to create the image are provided in the answer(s) (or links in the answers) on the marked duplicate. ie: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee530017 The easiest thing you may want to do instead of making a custom installer, since you seem to be only talking about reinstalling to the same computer, is just use Windows' Backup and make an image backup, store it, and when you want to reinstall Windows, just restore the backup instead.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Perhaps I explain it in a wrong way. I wish to have an image **and** I also wish it to be bootable. I've seen guides on both but not at the same time. Is it at all possible? I'd like to be able to boot up a computer with an empty HDD, stick the USB into it and make the process automatically set up everyth8ing for me. The restore process you're talking about requires that Windows already is installed and working on the machine, correct? I'd like my method to work even if the computer's got the partitions removed.

Comment: You don't need a working Windows for that method. Once you have an image (a backup windows image) you can just use *any* installer media for your OS to "repair" it, i.e. restore the backup.